# My program is not updating the table in sqlite JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, jdbc, javafx

My program is supposed to update the 'isAvail' in the Rooms table:

```
public void RemRoom() {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Rooms.db");
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("1");
            pst = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE " + tp + " set isAvail = 'false' where RoomID = '" + rm + "'");
            pst.execute();
            pst = con.prepareStatement("Select isAvail from " + tp + " Where RoomID = '" + rm + "'");
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(rs.toString());
            System.out.println("2");
            pst.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
```

It is not giving any errors to me but it is not changing the content of that cell.

[image]
Please help

Comment: ok sorry! can you undo the downvote please?

Comment: Why use `PreparedStatement ` if you are going to structure your queries like would if you just used `Statement`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is setting autocommit to `false` but it never commits. Once the connection is destroyed the changes will be lost.

Fix it by not disabling autocommit, or perform an explicit `con.commit()` before closing the connection.

Note that, for the queries that you show, there is no reason to disable autocommit because there is a single `UPDATE` query, and the `SELECT` query does not modify the database.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me. Tomorrow is my deadline you saved my life.

Comment: @DaBoss: great! You should consider accepting this answer.